# Finding latest month, year including the other fields

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Table1 is as follows :

```
Name    Number  Month   Year    Fee_Paid
Ravi    1       1       2010    100
Raju    2       1       2010    200
Kumar   3       1       2010    300
Ravi    1       2       2011    100
Raju    2       2       2011    200
Kumar   3       2       2011    300
Ravi    1       3       2012    100
Raju    2       3       2012    200
Kumar   3       3       2012    300
```

Result Should be as follows:

```
Name    Number  Month   Year    Fee_Paid
Ravi    1       3       2012    100
Raju    2       3       2012    200
Kumar   3       3       2012    300
```

The result should display the Latest year and Month including the Name, Number and fee_Paid in that period. Kindly help me.

Comment: Please describe what result you want if there is one more row in your sample data: `Kumar  4  4  2013  350`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a non-CTE solution:

```
select HighestYear.* from (
  select v1.* from visitors v1
  left join visitors v2
  on v1.number = v2.number and v1.year < v2.year
  where v2.year is null
) HighestYear
left join visitors v3
on HighestYear.number = v3.number and HighestYear.year = v3.year
and HighestYear.month < v3.month
where v3.month is null
```

[Example with more data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b396f/6)

Comment: Please note you have 5 extra columns that are all null (I think you want `HighestYear.*` vs. `*`). Even then it seems like your entire left join is unnecessary - the query returns the exact same results without it. And I'm not convinced they're the right results - it is hard to tell whether he wants all the rows from the last month found, or the last month for each user found. It seems to just be a coincidence that every user has one row in the last month.

Comment: Hi, I just added an example. I'm not sure which are those extra columns you mentioned.

Comment: Try running it in SQL Server (e.g. Management Studio). I don't know what that fiddler thing is doing but it is ignoring all of the columns from the copy of visitors aliased as v3. Also notice what happens if you delete one of the sample rows with year = 2012 and month = 4. Should that row with year = 2012 and month = 3 be there? I'm guessing not but we'll have to wait for an OP response I guess.

Comment: Sorry, I'm in Linux, so I can't test that. Regarding the column with month = 3, I thought it was expected to be there. I agree on waiting for the OP :) Update: Got it about the copy of columns, you're right! It replaces them because it has the same name and I forgot to update it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the last row for each name, regardless of which month was *their* last month:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
    SELECT Name, Number, [Month], [Year], [Fee_Paid],
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
      (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY [Year] DESC, [Month] DESC)
    FROM dbo.Table1
)
SELECT Name, Number, [Month], [Year], [Fee_Paid]
FROM x
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Number;
```

If you want all the rows from the last year/month combo found, regardless of name, the query is only slightly different:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
    SELECT Name, Number, [Month], [Year], [Fee_Paid],
      rn = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Year] DESC, [Month] DESC)
    FROM #x
)
SELECT Name, Number, [Month], [Year], [Fee_Paid]
FROM x
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Number;
```

Both of these queries give the result you seem to be after, but one of them is probably correct only by coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   Details.Name,
   Details.Number,
   Details.Month,
   Details.Year,
   Details.Fee_Paid
FROM
   (
   SELECT
      Name,
      MAX(Year) AS Year,
      MAX(Month) AS Month
   ) AS MaxValues
INNER JOIN MyTable AS Details ON
   Details.Name = MaxValues.Name
   AND Details.Year = MaxValues.Year
   AND Details.Month = MaxValues.Month
```